# Volume Cost Standard Deviation Calculation

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

In my trial to find the dispersion in the variable cost for a production process, below table is a sample indicating the recorded different output of the process in volume of production and costs.
Records Volume  Cost

[Volume-Cost outputs of a production process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXzEZ.png)

What is the best approach to measure the standard deviation of the variable cost given that the volume sample data isn't fixed as per the above table.

Comment: You can calculate the cost standard deviation for one volume unit, for instance.

Comment: I don't have the volumes normalised, as you see different volumes for each record.

Comment: But you can divide the volumes and the costs by the volumes. For record 1you have the cost 8900/5600 per volume unit.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the accurate approach I was looking forward to.